# Azure AD Joined PC Remote Desktop not working

Tags: azure-active-directory, remote-desktop

The article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/connect-to-remote-aadj-pc shows how to connect to an AAD joined PC from another AAD joined PC. I have followed these instructions.
The LENOVO Thinkcenter Edge machines are both brand new installs of Windows 10 updated to 10.0.19042.928 and registered to AAD with the same user. For testing, both PC are on the same network and have 10.6.2.xx IP's. Wireshark shows that the PC's can connect to each other. Remote Credential Guard has not been enabled. The standard "can't connect" error shows. Remote users now connected to Azure AD cannot work remotely. Can anyone advise?

[sysdm.cpl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOcLq.jpg)

[Remote Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w8w0.jpg)

[Enable Remote Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCLZw.jpg)

[Connecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvMWv.jpg)

[Failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbAe9.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

To make it working from any, even not AzureAD joint PC, just add

```
enablecredsspsupport:i:0
authentication level:i:2
```

at the end of RDP file. You may use any text editor to do it.

Credits to:
https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2129388-remote-desktop-to-azuread-machine-not-working

Comment: This only works if you change the default setting on the computer you are RDPing to and turn of NLA. This is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

To use remote desktop to an AzureAD connected PC, you need to change the Network Profile to Private for the network connection that you are using. This isn't documented and no error shows when you try to turn on Remote Desktop if Public is selected.

I was unable to get NLA working so followed this post to disable it..

[Disable NLA](https://superuser.com/questions/951330/windows-10-remote-desktop-connection-using-azure-ad-credentials/1089698)